# no matching function for call to ‘std::thread::thread(<unresolved overloaded function type>)’

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

```
void show_image(){
   // Create a Mat to store images
Mat cam_image;
ERROR_CODE err; 

// Loop until 'e' is pressed
char key = '';
while (key != 'e') {

    // Grab images 
    err = cam.grab();

    // Check if successful
    if (err == SUCCESS) {
        // Retrieve left image and show with OpenCV
        cam.retrieveImage(zed_image, VIEW_LEFT);
        cv::imshow("VIEW", cv::Mat(cam_image.getHeight(), cam_image.getWidth(), CV_8UC4, cam_image.getPtr<sl::uchar1>(sl::MEM_CPU)));
        key = cv::waitKey(5);
    } else
        key = cv::waitKey(5);
}
}
```

the above function is being called -threaded- by this function:

```
void startCAM()
{

    if(show_left){
     cam_call = std::thread(show_image);
    }
    //Wait for data to be grabbed
    while(!has_data)
      sleep_ms(1);
}
```

and I get the error:

```
     error: no matching function for call to ‘std::thread::thread(<unresolved     overloaded function type>)’
      cam_call = std::thread(show_image);
```

It should be noted I use no classes or objects, so show_image is not a member function

Comment: Try passing a *pointer* to the function using the address-of operator `&`.

Comment: This is weird, are you sure you're not doing anything else? Maybe there's another overload for `show_image()`? The code you posted seems to work: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e79e55a0a0deee1

Comment: thats weird, I am also getting these notes:

Comment: /usr/include/c++/5/thread:133:7: note: candidate: template<class _Callable, class ... _Args> std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...)
       thread(_Callable&& __f, _Args&&... __args)

Comment: my_main.cpp:289:43: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘_Callable’
     cam_call = std::thread(show_image);

Comment: note: candidate: std::thread::thread(std::thread&&)
     thread(thread&& __t) noexcept

Comment: /usr/include/c++/5/thread:128:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘std::thread&&’
/usr/include/c++/5/thread:122:5: note: candidate: std::thread::thread()
     thread() noexcept = default;
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/thread:122:5: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
CMakeFiles/my_viz.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/my_viz.dir/src/my_main.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/my_viz.dir/src/my_main.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/my_viz.dir/all' failed

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude no I am still getting the same error

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full errors (complete, copy-pasted, as text, without editing) and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error says `std::thread::thread(<unresolved overloaded function type>)`, which means there are multiple functions named `show_image`.

You need to choose one of those overloads. E.g.:

```
std::thread(static_cast<void(*)()>(show_image));
```

Comment: thnx , I was importing a forgotten and unused header file, where I had named another function with the same name!! solved the problem when I just stopped importing the header file!

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if your thread function is the same name as a function that already exists in the global scope.

For example, in my case, I had a function `recv` for receiving UDP socket data. When I renamed this to `receive`, the error vanished.